# svmperf multi-class model output

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, svm

I use [svm_multiclass_learn](http://svmlight.joachims.org/svm_multiclass.html) to learn the model of [multi-class classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification).

After learning I want to load the model file, read the weights and use them for classification, I do not want to use svm_multiclass_classify.

The problem is I don't understand the format of model file.

I am expecting it to be the matrix (number of classes on number of features), however it's just the list of features weight and I don't know how to interpret it.

It would be great if you could explain me the formal of model file.

**Addendum**

In addition, the documentation says nothing about bias (should be added as a feature or svm multiclass can handle it by itself)

Comment: Why don't you want to use svm_multiclass_classify?

Comment: I have a system, and I don't know the classification of test examples, in addition I don't know how fast test examples can be sent, therefore in order to optimize classification, I want to do classification by myself